# What causes a stock to make an EXTREMELY big move in a short period?

Tags: stocks

Today (8/19/20) I was paper trading a stock REDU.  I was in a short position without a stop loss and stock went from 6.74 to 7.48 or over 10% in a span of less than 30 seconds, faster than I could react to get out.  Is this due to low trade volume and the bid and ask became so wide?  or someone manipulating the market?

My question is how can I avoid this scenario in the future.  Would a stop loss work to get me out? or avoid these types of stocks in general.

Comment: So...you found yourself wanting a REDU of the trade?

Comment: A very brief answer is that, yes, this sort of thing happens in thin stocks - **low volume trading is a whole other world**.

Comment: Not really a low volume stock yesterday with over 4 million shares traded.

Answer (score 4):

It took one second for REDU to jump from $6.95 to $7.48 on minimal volume.  I saw no news to warrant this.

The B/A spread was tight and it traded over 4 million shares today so volume and spread weren't factors.

I can't say that someone is manipulating the market but this quick price rise is odd because it's hard to believe that the order book is so thin that it can gap on bare minimum  volume.

In a situation like this, when a stock gaps and you have a stop loss order within the gap, you're out of luck.  There's no way avoid losing the amount from your stop loss price up to the opening price after the gap.

Low priced stocks tend to be more volatile, often more so after an earnings announcement which happened to be yesterday.  You've witnessed that here.

Answer (score 0):

**This is common in low priced stocks**

It changed 10% but went up by $1.04.  Having a low price makes the stock more volatile for a few reasons.

**It's cheap.**  The barrier to entry is extremely low, so professionals and armchair traders alike can pick up a lot.  As a counterpoint, Google is ~$1500 a share, far fewer people will "take a chance" on it.

**You need to Cover Commissions and make money.**  Sometimes commissions are a cut of the price, but most of the time commissions are a flat fee in stock trading.  A 10% swing in google's price is ~$150.  Your stock 10% swing is ~$1.  This means you either have to own a substantial amount of stock or the price swing has to be higher to make it worth exiting a position.

Once you combine the fact that investors with no clue what they are doing can buy and sell on a whim, and that professional investors have to buy a decent chunk of a low-priced stock to make it worth their while, it's much easier to see why the price can swing much more.  A large investor entering or exiting a position would have a noticeable impact on price.

Armchair traders who decided to buy the stock because they added ".com" to the end of it, then dumped it when they realized it wasn't a website are another way larger swings are possible.

Comment: Most major discount brokers no longer charge commissions so for the most part,  that's not a factor anymore.  The rest of your explanation has nothing to do with why REDU rose sharply in price.